# Parsing FB2(XML) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec, fb2

Started to learn Haskell, I decided to get acquainted with Parsec, but there were problems. I'm trying to implement the parsing of the books in the format of FB2. On conventional tags ( text ) is good, but when the tag within a tag - does not work.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data FB2Doc = Node String FB2Doc
            | InnText String
            deriving (Eq,Show)

parseFB2 :: GenParser Char st [FB2Doc]
parseFB2 = many test

test :: GenParser Char st FB2Doc
test = do name <- nodeStart
          value <- getvalue
          nodeEnd
          return $ Node name value

nodeStart = do char '<'
               name <- many (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf "-_")
               char '>'
               return name

nodeEnd = do string "</"
             many (letter <|> digit)
             char '>'
             spaces 
gettext = do x <- many (letter <|> digit <|> oneOf "-_")
             return $ InnText x 

getvalue = do (nodeStart >> test) <|> gettext <|> return (Node "" (InnText ""))
main = do
         print $ parse parseFB2 "" "<h1><a2>ge</a2></h1> <genre>history_russia</genre>"
```

Comment: I haven't done a real round of debugging, but the `nodeStart >> test` clause of `getvalue` looks a little fishy: it has a `nodeStart` not matched by a `nodeEnd`; it throws away the name of the node that's started; and, since `test` immediately calls `many`, it can never return an empty list of nodes.

Comment: @FUZxxl, OP is doing this as a learning exercise, not, I presume, as a way to implement a production-quality XML parser.  So "use a library that does it for you" is not really fulfilling that goal.

Comment: Could you provide more information about how it does not work.  An error message, expected output, something.  These things help direct our attention to important parts of your code.

Comment: @luqui I removed my comment... You are right. I forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
getvalue = try test <|> gettext
```

The `try` is needed for empty nodes: `"<bla></bla>"`. `test` will consume the `'<'` of `</bla>`, and the `try` allows for backtracking.